# What is the Python equivalent to JDBC DatabaseMetaData?

Tags: python, jdbc, database-metadata

What is the Python equivalent to [DatabaseMetaData](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

Comment: There isn't an exact equivalent.  What information are you trying to pull and what type of database is it?

Comment: I need to be able to get tables, columns (size, scale, type, name), foreign keys, primary keys from Oracle and also MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a python-specific answer; in fact I don't know if Python data drivers have this sort of thing.  But maybe this info will help.

The ANSI SQL-92 and SQL-99 Standard requires the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Schema), which stores information regarding the tables in a catalog.

The metadata you seek can be retrieved with a query on views in that schema.

for example:

```
select column_name, is_nullable, data_type, character_maximum_length as maxlen 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'Products'
```

Not all databases implement that part of the standard. Oracle, for example, does not.

Fortunately, there are also database-specific tables that store that kind of info.

While Microsoft SQL Server supports the Information_Schema thing, there are also SQL Server-specific tables that give more metadata information. These are `[CatalogName].dbo.sysobjects` and `[CatalogName].dbo.sysolumns`.  Similar queries on these tables will give you the metadata you seek. Example:

```
select * from [CatalogName].dbo.syscolumns 
where id = 
    (Select id from [CatalogName].dbo.sysobjects where name = 'Products')
```

In Oracle, the ALL_TAB_COLUMNS table can give you the information:

```
select column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where table_name = 'EMP';
```

Whether you query the standard views or the db-specific views, you don't need ODBC to do these queries - you can use whatever db connection you have available for operational data, subject to security approvals of course.

Comment: Oracle of course does not seem to have this...
It appears I will need to go the ODBC route to get a standard set of functionality between dbs.

Comment: Hmm, that's a surprise!  With Oracle, there is an alternative data table you can query.  I'll update the answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

If your willing to use ODBC for data access then you could use pyodbc, http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Features.  Pyodbc allows you to call functions like SQLTables, which is equivalent to the JDBC getTables function.  The JDBC and ODBC functions to get to metadata are extremely similar.